# Add fragment to RedirectToPage

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

How to redirect to a page passing a fragment?

I'm unable to add fragment to RedirectToPage action. If I add "#" as part of string, it will be converted in %23 and therefore unuseful

PostAction

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
   if (!ModelState.IsValid) { return Page(); }

   _context.Attach(AnagraficaClientiContatti).State = EntityState.Modified;

   try{
       await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
   } 
   catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
   {
     if (!AnagraficaClientiContattiExists(
                 AnagraficaClientiContatti.AnagraficaClientiContattiID))
     {
        return NotFound();
     }
     else
     {
       throw;
      }
   }

   return RedirectToPage(
            "../Index", 
            new { id = Request.Query["idmaster"], 
                  pgm = Request.Query["pgm"], 
                  pgs1 = Request.Query["pgs1"], 
                  activetab = Request.Query["activetab"], 
                  searchstring = Request.Query["searchstring"] }
   );
}
```

and this work fine, but i need to redirect to above page with "#specificsection" at the end.

I tried to change the call to

```cs
return RedirectToPage(
        "../Index", 
        new { id = Request.Query["idmaster"], 
              pgm = Request.Query["pgm"], 
              pgs1 = Request.Query["pgs1"], 
              activetab = Request.Query["activetab"], 
              searchstring = Request.Query["searchstring"] 
                             + "#specificsection" }
);
```

but browser return a "wrong" url with `%23` instead `#`

> ?id=20&pgm=2&pgs1=2&activetab=custom-tabs-one-contatti&searchstring=text%23specificsection

No luck, passing fragment as third or fourth parameter (with third null ) in RedirectToPage, as i understood from documentation.

Can someone help me to understand what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Best

Massimo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razorpages.pagebase.redirecttopage?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-razorpages-pagebase-redirecttopage(system-string-system-string-system-object-system-string)) that takes a `string?`, `string?`, `object?`, `string?` for the page, page handler (which is `null`), route values and a fragment :

```cs
return RedirectToPage(
           pageName: "/Index", 
           pageHandler: null, 
           routeValues: new { 
                         id = Request.Query["idmaster"], 
                         pgm = Request.Query["pgm"], 
                         pgs1 = Request.Query["pgs1"],
                         activetab = Request.Query["activetab"], 
                         searchstring = Request.Query["searchstring"]},
           fragement: "specificsection")
);
```

From the docs for [`RedirectToPage(String, String, Object, String)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razorpages.pagebase.redirecttopage?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-razorpages-pagebase-redirecttopage(system-string-system-string-system-object-system-string))

> Parameters
>
> - string pageName // name of the page.
> - string pageHandler // page handler to redirect to.
> - Object routeValues // parameters for a route.
> - string fragment // fragment to add to the URL.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. I had misinterpreted the way to use the overload. Thanks again. Best. Massimo